# Replacing wall switch - box has 3 sets of wires (3 black, 3 red, 3 white, 3 copper)

Tags: electrical, wiring

Didn't take a photo of old set up.

I installed the new switch and now the light fixture works on and off but the outlets do not.

Is it an installation issue or light switch issue (bought single pole) - two black wires pigtailed to one screw on the switch and one black wire connected itself to other screw and copper pigtail to ground.

Comment: With the breaker off, take pictures of the wires.  The three green and three copper is odd, should only have three single wires of them, maybe a mix of green and bare, but not two sets.

Comment: 99.99999% chance that it's an installation issue, presuming that the original setup worked.

Comment: Sorry - no green wires just bare copper!

Comment: That makes more sense.  Should edit your question and fix the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> *Didn't take a photo of old set up.*

We all learn the hard way.

---

Three cables or conduits into a box like this *typically* means:

- Incoming power
- Switched device
- Ongoing power to an unswitched device (e.g., receptacles)

but there are some other possibilities. It is not always easy to figure it out, unfortunately.

The white wires are a key. White is *usually* neutral. If your 3 white wires were (and if so, hopefully still are) all connected together with a wire nut (or Wago connector) then they are neutrals. In that case, it is just a matter of figuring out which of the six other wires (3 black, 3 red) is which. *If the whites are not together, **stop** and post pictures for (hopefully) more help.*

A common setup is to use black for always-on hot and red for switched hot. But in that situation there is no need for red in most cables and so 2-wire (plus ground) black/white cable is used. So seeing red in all 3 cables (assuming they are cables, but the same would pretty much apply to individual wires in conduit as well) is a little unusual. What I recommend is:

- Turn off power
- Disconnect all the black and red wires from switches and each other (exception: if all the red wires are connected together then leave them as is and ignore them for the rest of this task - see MWBC note below), making notes (pictures!) of how things were connected previously in case that helps later
- Turn on power and use a non-contact voltage tester [like this Klein from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3HFgoBm):

[image: Klein NCVT]

to see which wire(s) have power. If more than one wire has power, **STOP** and ask for more help. If exactly one wire has power then you have found the incoming power. Then:

- Turn off power
- Connect the power black wire to one of the other black (or red if they were separate) wires
- Turn on power
- See what turned "on" - the light, receptacles that were dead, etc.
- Repeat for each black (and possibly red) wire

Now you should know what needs to be connected together. The power black needs to connect to (a) the switch and (b) all the other things that should be on all the time. The wire that, when connected to the power black wire, turned on the light goes to the other screw on the switch.

##### MWBC

A multi-wire branch circuit is a way to provide 2 x 120V and/or 240V power with only one more wire than a standard 120V circuit (i.e., both 120V hots use the same neutral). There are some places it works well and some (especially GFCI) where it doesn't. But in older houses it is quite common. If you have an MWBC then you will typically have black/red/white cable throughout the circuit. Since a light would only need one hot, the red wires would be all connected together in a switchbox for the light. If you have an MWBC then you *should* find that it is a *double* breaker, or two single breakers physically connected together ("handle tie") that turns off power to the circuit. If you don't have an MWBC then the red wires are a bit of a mystery here, at least to me.

Comment: The white & red are bundled up and capped off.  This was installed by electricians - and the switch was installed by them (the one I didn't take a pic of unfortunately).  It may be that I need to call them back.  I think it has to do with how I connected the 3 black wires.  I think the ground is fine that was pretty self explanatory with  the green screw....if this isn't as simple as I thought (or could have been had I taken a picture) maybe I should just have the original electricians come back.....

Comment: I do have a tester - similar to the pic you provided.

Comment: "bundled" is the key here - everything gets capped (except ground), the fact they are "bundled" and then capped means they are together. So your whites are all together - neutral - good! Your reds are all together means either (a) MWBC and all reds together for one of the hot legs or (b) they had /3 cable laying around and used instead of /2. Either way, that *should* mean it is just decoding the blacks - which you can do step-by-step as I described.

Comment: Great, appreciate the guidance!